# TextView doesn't wrap text correctly after resize

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, textview

I extended `FrameLayout` and overrode the `onLayout()` method. From there I call `layout()` on a `TextView` child to resize and relocate at will, but the wrapping of the text doesn't recalculate after the resize.

I've already tried `setText()` and `setWidth()`.

Sure there is something I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't get you. You want to set the height and width of textview according to your requirement????

Comment: you can use onpredrawlistner to set width of the textview. I think it will work. Set the width inside the predrawlistner according to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to [autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview).

Comment: Interesting, but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

call setEllipsize(null) to recalculate the wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Aladin Q's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10798509/399105), this is what I used to handle pre ICS and ICS:

```
// pre ICS
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < 14) {
    setEllipsize(null);
// ICS and above
} else {
    setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setEllipsize(null) will work well before "ICS" (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) but not after.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870312/android-imagegetter-images-overlapping-text) for details.