# Why the last image crops when HTML is loaded into Android TextView

Tags: android, html, image, android-asynctask, textview

I'm trying to display images in android TextView. I am following this solution: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424512/android-html-imagegetter-as-asynctask) It works well. But the images are overlapped, then I changed onPostExecute() method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870312/android-imagegetter-images-overlapping-text/10208504#10208504). This solved the problem with overlappings. However, the last image is always cropped more than a half of it's height. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

TextView is not best tool to display images. Most general thing to remove crops - wrap textview with scrollview container.